# What TV episode has a child go missing and return un-aged when their parents are very old?

Tags: story-identification, the-twilight-zone

All I can remember is that a couple's daughter/son goes missing.  They are talking to the police I think and they are told that their child may have passed a sign that said quick sand.

Fast-forward to years later when the parents are old. They get a knock at the door and it is their missing child, but he/she has not aged at all.  I think the little girl/boy came back to take the mother to heaven.

I thought it was a Twilight Zone episode or the Outer Limits, but I have searched all episodes of both and I cannot remember what this show was. Does anyone know?

Comment: It sounds like Flight of the Navigator; http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091059/

Comment: Flight of the navigator was a movie.  I remember it well.  This was a show like the twilight zone or outer limits.  I remember specifically the thought of the girl falling into quick sand and then returning years later to take her mother to heaven, or something like that.  Def. not the flight of the navigator.

Comment: I finally found out what it was after searching for a long time.  It was a show in the 80's by Steven Spielberg called Amazing Stories.  Season 2 Episode Without Dianne.  Funny how I remembered something from my childhood, but after watching it again, it seemed pretty stupid.

Comment: @user21512, you should go ahead and make your comment an answer and accept it

Answer (score 5):

Per the comment above, the answer is
[Amazing Stories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazing_Stories_%28TV_series%29) (Season 2, episode 19)

The episode is called "[Without Diana](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511131/)"

The blurb for the episode is;

> "1946 Father-Daughter Easter Picnic: Eight-year-old Diana bears a
>   grudge against her father who has just returned from World War II,
>   because she doesn't understand why he had to leave her several years
>   ago. During the game, she vanishes in the woods. He later meets his long lost daughter who appears to him exactly as she appeared forty years ago."

[image]

Comment: Anyone else notice that "Amazing Stories" seems to show up as the correct answer a LOT? I guess that just means the show had a wider influence than anyone thought at the time.

Comment: @omegacron - We should just be pleased that it wasn't "Light Brigade" from the  Outer Limits

Answer (score -4):

This show is called Resurrection. You can go to youtube and type Resurrection and the trailer will pop up. The show will air on ABC.

Comment: Please link to a Youtube video (or Wikipedia or whatever) of this. If you can provide corroboration, your answer deserves to be awarded as correct.

Comment: Since the OP **already confirmed** that the show was "Amazing Stories", I remain unconvinced that this is the right answer.

Comment: Causality prevents this from being correct, but this may be useful to future visitors.